# How to write a query that uses variables in sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a query that works in mysql I would like to write using sqlalchemy.
Simplified version of my query looks like:

```
set @num = NULL, @val = NULL;
select group_name, count(*) from
(select @num := if(@last=id, @num+1, 1) as num,
        @last := id as last,
        group_name
order by group_name)
where num<=100
group by group_name;
```

My problem is setting variables @num and @last and then using them in a query. I know I can do it using execute (something like [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/iC4xmU8aeZQ)), but I would prefer to use sqlalchemy tools for building queries instead of row sql (for maintainance and compatibility reasons). Is it possible?